# how to add record separator (ASCII 30) in java string

Tags: java, ascii

Example:

```
String FirstName;
String LastName;

String FullName = FirstName +"\RS"+ LastName;  // Error
```

but \RS is not supported in java.

Comment: i know its seems like silly question but i am struck up here since split function removing all record separators at the end of the string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if you know the ASCII value, then use it. `char` represents a character with ASCII value:

```
char record_separator = 0x1e;
String s = "hello" + record_separator + "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: `\u241E`

Have you tried this: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241e/index.htm

Comment: This is a visual representation for the record separator, not the record separator itself. The correct solution would be `"\u001e"`.